# Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror' when trying to run Pay Java Seed in Activator UI

Tags: java, playframework

I am new to Play framework. I am trying to run Play Java Seed but the build fails with the error "Missing dependency object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror", required by /home/saipreethi/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the Activator UI is using sbt. But I haven't changed any thing in any of the build files. Could you please elaborate on what exactly i need to check? Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

Okay finally figured it out. The problem was due to Java version. I was using openjdk 9. But turns out Play framework works with Oracle's Java 8. This was causing the build error.